# Check screen width and then pass variable on php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to check the screen resolution of the user. Now the solution is to check the screen resolution with AJAX and then pass variable to a PHP page. I have tried this but it does not work.

```
var width = $(window).width();

$.ajax({
    url: "/the-php-page-i-want-to-show-with-output.php",
    data: {
        screenwidth: width
    } 
}).done(function() {
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

and the php page `/the-php-page-i-want-to-show-with-output.php`:

```
<?
    $width11 = $_REQUEST['screenwidth'];

    if ($width11 < 769)
    {
        echo '<div class="test">mobile</div>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<div class="test">desktop</div>';
    }
?>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: `$width11` will be a string, but you're comparing it to an integer value.

Comment: i tried add <?

    $width11 = $_REQUEST['screenwidth'];
    $widthfinal = (int)$width11;

    
if($widthfinal < 769){echo '<div class="guru">mobile</div>';}
else {echo '<div class="guru">desktop</div>';}
?>   but same problem , can you show me a example, the problem is aoutput some time the div "mobile" also in desktop

Comment: If that's what you're trying to do, then use CSS media queries. AJAX is a rather odd solution to this problem.

Comment: no this is only a example the output is more complex

Comment: Do you want to add this div in html?

Comment: yes, but the div is only example

Comment: Try this.   screenwidth: window.innerWidth